# Can we config PHPStorm not to recognize mssql library

Tags: php, windows, ide, phpstorm, php-5.5

The IDE is using PHP language level 5.5 and I don't want it to recognize mssql library because I'm on window environment.

mssql library functions will cause errors on php 5.5 application and these errors can't be detected by IDE

Can we remove mssql library recognition?

Comment: `mssql`?! That's still perfectly fine, AFAIK.

Comment: I will edit the question to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CANNOT tell IDE to "forget" any specific class ... unless you alter PhpStorm's installation and physically remove stub file for it (which you will have to do for every new version).

---

You could re-declare the class/functions yourself **instead** and add `@deprecated` tag to PHPDoc comments for them -- this will tell IDE to mark them as deprecated and warn you (if corresponding inspection is turned ON -- `Settings | Inspections | PHP | General | Deprecated`)